# jQuery Animation, Chaining, .each() and .animate() (or fadeIn() and fadeOut())

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a bit of a trouble trying to figure this out today, i want to make 5 items inside my DOM (which is listed under the same attribute element, $('.elements')) fade in and out, and after reading up a bit on the API i thought .each() would be a fabulous idea to implement a fade in and fade out showcase gallery.

However, i'm currently using:

```
$('.elements').each(function() {
    $(this).fadeIn(2000).delay(200).fadeOut(2000).show();
})
```

but everything gets faded in and out at once.

How do i do a sequential effect where everything is chained together and it starts from the first item in the list (a.k.a - $('elements').eq(0)?) down to the last one, and then restarts again?

Do i really need a while loop to do this in javascript/jquery? I was hoping there would be a similar function that i could chain for jQuery to perform to reduce load and filesize.

Also, is there a way to restrict the images from overflowing out from my div?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
(function loop() {
  $('.elements').each(function() {
    var $self = $(this);
    $self.parent().queue(function (n) {
      $self.fadeIn(2000).delay(200).fadeOut(2000, n);
    });
  }).parent().promise().done(loop);
}());
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uWGVN/2/

**updated** to have it looping without end.

---

**2nd update**: a different, probably more readable, approach:

```
(function fade(idx) {
  var $elements = $('.elements');
  $elements.eq(idx).fadeIn(2000).delay(200).fadeOut(2000, function () {
    fade(idx + 1 < $elements.length ? idx + 1 : 0);
  });
}(0));
```

​demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uWGVN/3/

Comment: wow, this is exactly what i was looking for! Just one question though, what does function(n) take in? I understand the usage of a .queue function but just not that part where you add in an argument.

Comment: You can think of `n` as the next callback in the queue. If one uses the queue in this way you're responsible to advance the queue by calling the supplied callback.

Comment: ah okay. so in basic english terms, i have a long list of elements, each seperated into a single queue where each element fades in and out for a total of 4000 milliseconds and a 200 millisecond delay inbetween, and when it is finished it loops again via the .promise() method.

Comment: Not exactly. To have the animations run one after the other you need to use the same queue for every element. That's the reason I'm using `.parent()`. Basically I'm using the animation queue of the parent to fadeIn/Out the child elements.

Comment: @RenoYeo I added a second version, which I personally use more often as I find it easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a callback

offical doc :

```
('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

and call the same function with i++ et $('.elements').eq(i)

http://jsfiddle.net/dFnNL/

Comment: It's still chaining, but not exactly what i was looking for. Yoshi has a better version, where he more or less displays it one at a time on a visual perspective. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

For your overflowing , style it with CSS:

```
div.(class) { position:relative; overflow:hidden; }
```

Comment: Right, i did vaguely remember a overflow attribute. It worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Beautiful way :

```
(function hideNext(jq){
        jq.eq(0).hide("slow", function(){
            (jq=jq.slice(1)).length && hideNext(jq);
        });

})($('a'))
```

last first :

```
(function hideNext(jq){
                jq.eq(jq.length-1).hide("slow", function(){
                    (jq=jq.slice(0,length-1)).length && hideNext(jq);
                });

})($('a'))
```